# Excluding the GroupBoxes that are inside another GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

Let's say I have 7 group boxes but some of them also have group box inside them and some do not.
now if I want to iterate through those 7 group boxes and apply something to them, is there a way that I can exclude those Child group boxes from this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

though i question the choice of implementation (can you use polymorphism instead? what exactly are you trying to do?), there is a Parent property, e.g.

```
void soSomething(Control ctrl)
{
    if (ctrl is GroupBox && (ctrl.Parent is null || !(ctrl.Parent is GroupBox)))
    {
         //do something here
    }
    foreach(Control child in ctrl.Controls)
    {
        doSomething(child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark them with the tag property, or something.

Comment: thanks, so there is not such a thing like a "parent" or so property that I can check on each of them? right?

Comment: not that I'm aware of, but it could be associated with a container or hwnd property